# html5 video is not working in android devices

Tags: html, video

i have used the following code for html5 video in android browsers,

```
<video id="v1" autoplay preload="true" width="720" height="576"  >
<source src="videos/bj.m4v"/>
<source src="videos/bj.webm" type="video/webm" />
<source src="videos/bj.ogv" type="video/ogg" /> 
</video>
```

Please help me how can we play html5 videos in all android devices.

how to play a html5 video in iphone browser. mostly the videos are playing in the default player but i want the video to be play in the browser itself.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can't play video backgrounds in smartphone browsers.

Most mobile browsers aren't compatible to HTML5.

You should put an image as background using @media

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp